# list files in a directory based on timestamp

Tags: bash, shell

In bash, is there a command line to list all the files in a directory based on a timestamp. e.g.,

```
\ls -ltr dir/file*

-rw-r--r-- 1 anon  root   338 Aug 28 12:30 g1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon  root  2.9K Aug 28 12:32 g2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon  root  2.9K Aug 28 12:41 g3.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon  root  2.9K Aug 28 13:03 g4.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 anon  root  2.9K Aug 28 13:05 g5.log
```

I want to list all the files that have timestamp before `Aug 28 13:00`.

UPDATE :

```
]$ find -version
GNU find version 4.2.27
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION SELINUX
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use find command if you know the number of days

```
find ./ -mtime -60
```

+60 means you are looking for a file modified 60 days ago.

60 means less than 60 days.

60 If you skip + or - it means exactly 60 days.

Comment: `-mtime -60` means less than 60 days?

Answer (score 4):

The time displayed by `ls -la` is the last modification date. To list all the files in a directory which have been last modified before `2013/08/28 13:00:00`, use the following `find` command:

```
find -maxdepth 0 -type f -newermt '2013-08-28 13:00:00'
```

Comment: somehow -newermt is not available for the find version I am using. It complains, `find: invalid predicate '-newermt'`

Comment: can you add the output of `find -version` to your question, or a pastebin?

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
read T < <(exec date -d 'Aug 28 13:00' '+%s') && find /dir -type f | while IFS= read -r FILE; do read S < <(exec stat -c '%Y' "$FILE") && [[ S -lt T ]] && echo "$FILE"; done
```

Also, if your `find` comand support `-newerXY` you could have this:

```
find /dir -type f -not -newermt 'Aug 28 13:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

Touch a file with the time stamp and find all older files.

```
touch -d 'Aug 28 13:00' /tmp/timestamp
find . ! -newer /tmp/timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

I love pure bash solutions (well, not considering `date` and `stat`):

```
dateStr='Aug 28 13:00'

timestamp=$(date -d "$dateStr" +%s)
for curFile in *; do
    curFileMtime=$(stat -c %Y "$curFile")
    if (( curFileMtime < timestamp )); then
        echo "$curFile"
    fi
done
```

The results are not going to be sorted, because you didn't mention that you want them in sorted order.

Answer (score 1):

First, find out how old a file must be to have a timestamp earlier than (e.g.) Aug 28 at 13:00.

```
now=$(date +%s)
then=$(date +%s --date "2013-08-28 13:00")
minimum_age_in_minutes=$(( (now-then)/60 ))
```

Then, use `find` to find all files that are at least `minimum_age_in_minutes` old.

```
find "$dir" -mmin "+$minimum_age_in_minutes"
```